# How to correctly join() thread in a singleton

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton

I created a simple example.
There is a window with two buttons: Start and Stop.

When you click Start action : `TTestThread::get().start();`

When you click Stop action : `TTestThread::get().stop();`

TTestThread class code (singleton):

```
void TTestThread::run()
{
    while (_runned) {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
    }
}

void TTestThread::start()
{
    _runned.store(true);
    _testThread = std::thread(
        [this]() {
            run();
        });
}

void TTestThread::stop()
{
    _runned.store(false);
    if (_testThread.joinable()) {
        _testThread.join();
    }
}

TTestThread::~TTestThread()
{
    
}

TTestThread& TTestThread::instance()
{
    static TTestThread instance;
    return instance;
}

TTestThread& TTestThread::get()
{
    static std::once_flag flag;
    std::call_once(flag, [] { instance(); });
    return instance();
}
```

```
class TTestThread {

private:
    std::atomic<bool> _runned;
    std::thread _testThread;

private:
    void run();
    TTestThread() = default;
    ~TTestThread();
    static TTestThread& instance();

protected:
public:
    static TTestThread& get();
    void start();
    void stop();
};
```

If the user presses Start, then Stop, then closes the program - everything is correct. If the user presses Start and then closes the program, the exception "Abnormal program termination" is thrown.

How to act correctly at the end of the program if only the Start button was pressed, but the Stop button was not pressed?

Comment: Call `stop` in your window close handler (or register an `atexit` handler).

Comment: This is a really simple solution, which for some reason did not occur to me :) It works, but is it really the best practice?

Comment: Singletons are already not a good idea, but combined with threads and unit testing even more so. The sleep in a unit test environment also looks suspicious. Consider a redesign, have a look at how dependency injection works. You can make a wrapper class can execute functions (lambdas), in production this wrapper can use a thread in a test environment you can give it an execute(_next) method so your test has full control over what gets executed when.